# Does a PC age in terms of hardware and performance?

Tags: benchmarking

Let's say you are using a personal computer for 10 years. Assuming all software things are the same, will the computer get the same scores on benchmarks as 10 years ago? If not, why?

Comment: This has nothing to do with computer science. *Maybe* the guys on [electronics.SE] would appreciate the question, but maybe not. Ask in their chat.